# Spring Boot application doesn't start when deployed to Tomcat inside Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, tomcat, java-11

I've migrated my Spring Boot application to Java 11 and since then, it fails to start on Tomcat inside Eclipse. To be precise, Tomcat starts, but no output from the Spring Boot application is present, like if it wouldn't be deployed. This also happens only after Java 11 migration and only when using Tomcat inside Eclipse, when I deploy war file to the same but standalone Tomcat it works.

Do you have any idea what could be causing this? Or should I just consider it Eclipse problem and wait for newer version?

I'm using Eclipse 4.10.0 2018-12, Tomcat 9.0.14, Java 11.0.2, Spring Boot 2.1.1.

EDIT:

Log from Tomcat starting inside Eclipse
https://pastebin.com/ws2K1FUV

```
úno 07, 2019 10:23:20 DOP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.14
úno 07, 2019 10:23:20 DOP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Dec 6 2018 21:13:53 UTC
úno 07, 2019 10:23:20 DOP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version number: 9.0.14.0
úno 07, 2019 10:23:20 DOP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 10
úno 07, 2019 10:23:20 DOP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.0
úno 07, 2019 10:23:20 DOP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
úno 07, 2019 10:23:20 DOP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2
úno 07, 2019 10:23:20 DOP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           11.0.2+7-LTS
úno 07, 2019 10:23:20 DOP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
úno 07, 2019 10:23:20 DOP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\PATH\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
úno 07, 2019 10:23:20 DOP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.14
úno 07, 2019 10:23:20 DOP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\PATH\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
úno 07, 2019 10:23:20 DOP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.14
úno 07, 2019 10:23:20 DOP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\PATH\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
úno 07, 2019 10:23:20 DOP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
úno 07, 2019 10:23:20 DOP. org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.19] using APR version [1.6.5].
úno 07, 2019 10:23:20 DOP. org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
úno 07, 2019 10:23:20 DOP. org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
úno 07, 2019 10:23:20 DOP. org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
INFO: OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.1a  20 Nov 2018]
úno 07, 2019 10:23:20 DOP. org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
úno 07, 2019 10:23:21 DOP. org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
úno 07, 2019 10:23:21 DOP. org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Server initialization in [1,692] milliseconds
úno 07, 2019 10:23:21 DOP. org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
úno 07, 2019 10:23:21 DOP. org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.14]
úno 07, 2019 10:23:23 DOP. org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
WARNING: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [858] milliseconds.
úno 07, 2019 10:23:24 DOP. org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
úno 07, 2019 10:23:25 DOP. org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
úno 07, 2019 10:23:25 DOP. org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
úno 07, 2019 10:23:25 DOP. org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in [3,088] milliseconds
```

Log from Tomcat starting as standalone
https://pastebin.com/LLZ4Hmcr

```
07-Feb-2019 11:28:33.241 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.14
07-Feb-2019 11:28:33.246 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Dec 6 2018 21:13:53 UTC
07-Feb-2019 11:28:33.246 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 9.0.14.0
07-Feb-2019 11:28:33.247 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 10
07-Feb-2019 11:28:33.247 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.0
07-Feb-2019 11:28:33.248 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
07-Feb-2019 11:28:33.248 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2
07-Feb-2019 11:28:33.248 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           11.0.2+7-LTS
07-Feb-2019 11:28:33.249 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
07-Feb-2019 11:28:33.249 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.14
07-Feb-2019 11:28:33.250 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.14
07-Feb-2019 11:28:33.251 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
07-Feb-2019 11:28:33.252 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
07-Feb-2019 11:28:33.253 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
07-Feb-2019 11:28:33.253 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.14\conf\logging.properties
07-Feb-2019 11:28:33.254 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
07-Feb-2019 11:28:33.255 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
07-Feb-2019 11:28:33.259 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
07-Feb-2019 11:28:33.260 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dspring.config.location=file:C:/PATH/conf/
07-Feb-2019 11:28:33.261 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dlogging.config=file:C:/PATH/conf/logback-spring.xml
07-Feb-2019 11:28:33.262 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
07-Feb-2019 11:28:33.262 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.14
07-Feb-2019 11:28:33.263 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.14
07-Feb-2019 11:28:33.264 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.14\temp
07-Feb-2019 11:28:33.265 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.19] using APR version [1.6.5].
07-Feb-2019 11:28:33.266 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
07-Feb-2019 11:28:33.266 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
07-Feb-2019 11:28:33.275 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.1a  20 Nov 2018]
07-Feb-2019 11:28:33.368 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
07-Feb-2019 11:28:34.405 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
07-Feb-2019 11:28:34.410 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [1,710] milliseconds
07-Feb-2019 11:28:34.464 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
07-Feb-2019 11:28:34.465 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.14]
07-Feb-2019 11:28:34.486 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.14\webapps\app.war]
07-Feb-2019 11:28:44.103 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
07-Feb-2019 11:28:44.172 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.14\webapps\app.war] has finished in [9,685] ms
07-Feb-2019 11:28:44.174 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.14\webapps\docs]
07-Feb-2019 11:28:44.211 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.14\webapps\docs] has finished in [38] ms
07-Feb-2019 11:28:44.212 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.14\webapps\examples]
07-Feb-2019 11:28:44.686 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.14\webapps\examples] has finished in [475] ms
07-Feb-2019 11:28:44.687 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.14\webapps\host-manager]
07-Feb-2019 11:28:44.734 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.14\webapps\host-manager] has finished in [47] ms
07-Feb-2019 11:28:44.735 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.14\webapps\manager]
07-Feb-2019 11:28:44.775 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.14\webapps\manager] has finished in [40] ms
07-Feb-2019 11:28:44.776 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.14\webapps\ROOT]
07-Feb-2019 11:28:44.809 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.14\webapps\ROOT] has finished in [33] ms
07-Feb-2019 11:28:44.814 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
07-Feb-2019 11:28:44.825 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
07-Feb-2019 11:28:44.831 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [10,420] milliseconds
```

Both logs are using the same version of Tomcat and same version of application. But the Eclipse one just ends as it is here. Standalone one starts to write Spring Boot output to console after this.

Comment: a spring-boot application doesn't need to be deployed to a tomcat, it has it's own

Comment: post your logs please

Comment: I've added logs to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still wasn't able to make it run the same way as previously with Java 8, but I've found out that even when the application is built as war and supposed to run on external Tomcat, I can still run it in Eclipse as Spring Boot application using embedded Tomcat. This isn't exactly what I wanted, but it at least allows to build the application the way we need and at the same time be able to debug it directly in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this by producing a war and following the below steps:
 1. Change your maven packaging
`<packaging>war</packaging>`
 2. Add this dependency

```xml
<dependency>

   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

3. extend the SpringBootServletInitializer

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootTomcatApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
}
```

Comment: I think you've missed the part that it worked before migration to Java 11, I don't have a problem with running Spring Boot as war file on Tomcat in general. Just with the specific technologies.